# Google Analytics Event Tracking Unallowed document protocol. Aborting hit

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to set up google analytics to track an event, the event will basically be fired from a back end which will load up an HTML page that sends the event over to google.  I have the following code in my html page:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'event', 'Telephone', 'Answered', '123456789', 112);  
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign');">12345</a>
```

I have the google analytics debugger installed, and I have followed the documentation at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events I have even done a simple href link using the exact example, but it just doesn't work, all  get in the debugger is:

Running command: ga("send", "event", "Telephone", "Answered", "123456789", 112)

Unallowed document protocol. Aborting hit.

Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "render", Function)

Running command: ga("send", "event", "Videos", "play", "Fall Campaign")

Unallowed document protocol. Aborting hit.

I am running this locally just to test it out, if that makes a difference?

I've also been checking Analytics real time events and nothing has been registered.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've sorted it, it works fine when it's loaded on the server, but not locally!

Cheers